# perltk: highlighting text in textfield and updating labels

Tags: perl, tk-toolkit, perltk

Using TK on Windows XP.

```
my $mw = new MainWindow;
my $text1 = $mw->Text(-width=>20, -height=>10)
            ->place(-x=>350, -y=>460); 

my $showlabel = $mw->Label(-text => "nothing selected")
            ->place(-x=>50, -y=>120);

$text1->configure( -command => sub { 
    $showlabel->configure(-text => "You selected:\t" . 
                          $text1->getSelected() 
                         )
  } 
);
```

After running the code, `$showlabel` is not updating whenever I highlight any text.
Can anyone please help?

Comment: Using what libraries on which platform?

Comment: using tk;
i am working on win xp.
language is perl

Comment: What's with `$ow`, is that a typo?  Then you probably are not using `strict` and `warnings`, so start with that.

Comment: sorry $mw is mistyped as $ow.And i have used 'warnings'

Comment: Edited the question to fix the typo.  Also added the platform info.  For what it's worth, please note that you can and should edit your question so that comments can focus on the actual question.

Comment: ok i got you...can you now please help me??...its really important.

Comment: Why are you expecting the "command" call to be invoked?  Where do you call dump?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**: code without button.

And don't forget to call `MainLoop` at the end of your program to display the window. Without it, nothing will ever happen.

Try this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Tk;

my $mw = new MainWindow;
my $text1 = $mw->Text(-width => 20, -height => 10)
                   ->place(-x => 350, -y => 460);
my $showlabel = $mw->Label(-text => "nothing selectd")
                       ->place(-x => 50, -y => 120);
$text1->bind('<KeyPress>'     , \&sel);
$text1->bind('<ButtonPress>'  , \&sel);
$text1->bind('<ButtonRelease>', \&sel);

MainLoop;

sub sel
{
    $showlabel->configure(-text => "You selected:\t" . $text1->getSelected);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help,
But actually i dont want a button...i just want that the label should automatically get updated when i select some text from the text field.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$text1->bind( '<<Selection>>', sub {
  $showlabel->configure(-text => "You selected:\t".$text1->getSelected() )
} );
```